# New HP Pavilion 500 has very weak WiFi reception signal

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, hp-pavilion, wireless-adapter

So I just bought a new desktop computer:

- **Model**: HP 500-280ef
- **CPU**: intel i7 4770, 3.8ghz, 8mo cache
- **GPU**: nVidia 750 2Gb DDR5
- **RAM**: 8Gb
- **OS**: Windows 8.1
- **Wireless Adapter**: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 802.11/b/g/n
- **Wireless Adapter Driver Version:** 10.0.0.1.263

And I have a very serious problem with the WiFi reception signal.

Sometimes it works normally (high reception signal) and sometimes it just go off completely with of course all the pain that happens in between that make my internet super slow, the strange part is that I was always using my Acer laptop in the same room and my MacBook too, and they both work fine.

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Also after few search it seems that this is a common problem with many HP Pavilion 500-series, so if this is a hardware issue, will buying an USB wireless adapter solve the problem?

Comment: Does the Wi-Fi antenna have an extension lead for you to try putting it in a better position?

Comment: In addition, is the Wi-Fi antenna out the back of the desktop?  It was on my (now gone) desktop and did not have excellent reception accordingly. If HP supplied the wireless, contact HP support.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your driver from the device manager [devmgmt.msc].

I know that's kind of a lame 'try turning it off and then turning it back on again' approach, but it really does work for a lot of vague/non-specific issues like these.

Does the laptop perform any better on other wireless networks? Try taking it to a friend's house or McDonald's and connecting. I know the other devices in your house working almost completely rules out a network hardware problem, but I've seen specific devices be 'alergic' to certain networks or WAPs for reasons that don't make sense to try and diagnose until you test it on someone else's WiFi.

Also, are there any noticeable sources of interference near your laptop that aren't near the other devices in the room? i.e., are you setting this laptop on top of a constantly running microwave or right next to a cordless phone set?

Worst-case-senario, I wouldn't buy a USB wNIC just yet as most newer laptops have easily-accessible and field-replacable internal wNICs. At least you wouldn't have to cart around yet another USB device if you end up needing a new wNIC.

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is not a with a portable computer (laptop) it's with a Desktop computer. I tried turning it off and on i also reinstalled the driver (i saw that there is a newer version i will try it too and say what happens) i also tried changing the wifi channel from the router and finally there is no interference because my 2 other laptops, my 2 phones works perfectly and have no wireless issues at all, this is happening only with the desktop. could it be because it's on the ground ??? that would be so weird though...

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that this was a desktop platform. I'm assuming then that your Qualcomm wNIC is a PCIe card?

Definitely update to the latest driver, but if that doesn't work I'd want to try a different wNIC in the PC before trying anything else.

Comment: i just updated to the latest driver, the internet speed is kinda okay but i never get full signal like on the laptop (laptops always show 6/6 or 5/6) this pc never bypass 3/6. And i think buying a usb adapter is cheaper than a new card :p Thank you

Comment: You're right, that will be much cheaper. As a sidenote, I never liked Qualcomm tech. I've never had this problem, but I've had others and I pretty much won't buy anything that's not Netgear or Linksys.

Comment: okay thank you, i'll try to avoid it in the future ^^